# Android Java: App Crashes when onClick button pressed

Tags: java, android

I have a countdown app with 3 additional countdown pages. The countdown on each page works as it should. I have added to the java code on 1 page a select image button, meaning I can select a different image from the gallery to be displayed.

When I now click on the button for that particular page the app crashes.

Error message from Logcat -

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method my40th(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'my40th'
```

Where am I going wrong? I have the same code on another test countdown with singular page and it works fine.

This is the java code for that particular page:

```
package com.example.countdown;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class my40th extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView txtDay, txtHour, txtMinute, txtSecond;
private TextView tvEventStart;
private Handler handler;
private Runnable runnable;
private Bundle savedInstanceState;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
    myImage = findViewById( R.id.imgView );
    sp = getSharedPreferences( "setback", MODE_PRIVATE );
    if (sp.contains( "imagepath" )) {
        storedpath = sp.getString( "imagepath", "" );
        myImage.setImageBitmap( BitmapFactory.decodeFile( storedpath ) );
    }

    txtDay = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.txtDay );
    txtHour = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.txtHour );
    txtMinute = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.txtMinute );
    txtSecond = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.txtSecond );
    tvEventStart = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.tveventStart );

    countDownStart();
}

private void countDownStart() {
    handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            handler.postDelayed( this, 1000 );
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "dd-MM-yyyy" );
                Date futureDate = dateFormat.parse( "31-8-2020" );
                Date currentDate = new Date();
                if (!currentDate.after( futureDate )) {
                    long diff = futureDate.getTime()
                            - currentDate.getTime();
                    long days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                    diff -= days * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                    long hours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
                    diff -= hours * (60 * 60 * 1000);
                    long minutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
                    diff -= minutes * (60 * 1000);
                    long seconds = diff / 1000;
                    txtDay.setText( "" + String.format( "%02d", days ) );
                    txtHour.setText( "" + String.format( "%02d", hours ) );
                    txtMinute.setText( "" + String.format( "%02d", minutes ) );
                    txtSecond.setText( "" + String.format( "%02d", seconds ) );
                } else {
                    tvEventStart.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                    tvEventStart.setText( "Holiday is over, get a new one booked ASAP!" );
                    textViewGone();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed( runnable, 1 * 1000 );
}

public void textViewGone() {
    findViewById( R.id.LinearLayout1 ).setVisibility( View.GONE );
    findViewById( R.id.LinearLayout2 ).setVisibility( View.GONE );
    findViewById( R.id.LinearLayout3 ).setVisibility( View.GONE );
    findViewById( R.id.LinearLayout4 ).setVisibility( View.GONE );
    findViewById( R.id.textViewheader2 ).setVisibility( View.GONE );
}

public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI );
    startActivityForResult( galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG );
}
String mFilePath;
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;
String imgpath, storedpath;
SharedPreferences sp;
ImageView myImage;


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult( requestCode, resultCode, data );
    try {
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query( selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null );
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex( filePathColumn[0] );
            imgpath = cursor.getString( columnIndex );
            Log.d( "path", imgpath );
            cursor.close();

            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sp.edit();
            edit.putString( "imagepath", imgpath );
            edit.commit();


            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( imgpath );

            myImage.setImageBitmap( myBitmap );
        } else {
            Toast.makeText( this, "You haven't picked an Image",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText( this, "Oops something's went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG )
                .show();
    }
    }
 }
```

Comment: post the full stacktrace error and your xml layout for that particular page

Comment: use setOnClickListner instead on onClick attribute and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all those who answered my question, I managed to get it resolved, was a very simple fix.

Change the R.Layout.activity_MainActivity to my40th and it worked.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.**activity_my40th**);
```

Answer (score 0):

remove all lines with `android:onClick` in your `R.layout.activity_main` XML (you should put this in question)

you probably have lines like this:

```
android:onClick="my40th"
```

which means: when user click this `View` call method my40th(View v) passing clicked `View` as `v`. you don't have such method, in fact this is name of your `Activity`/class.

you have to create proper methods for buttons, for example your `loadImagefromGallery(View view)` method will work and get called when user press button/view with defined `android:onClick="loadImagefromGallery"`

edit: your XML should look like this

```
<Button android:id="@+id/my40th" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/xmas"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:onClick="loadImagefromGallery"
    android:text="My 40th"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="50sp"/>
```

note line

```
    android:onClick="loadImagefromGallery"
```

check this code and get back with result and full `Exception` if still occurs, also put this XML in question ALWAYS, don't post such a big part of code in comment...

Comment: When the user clicks the view method (i.e my40th) it should take you to that specific page with the countdown. Then when on that page there is a button to change the background image, when that button is pressed, it should then load from gallery.

Comment: first of all and again: you don't have `my40th` method, you have `my40th` class... inside `onClick` you have to put method reference, so in you case it would be like in my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

In your `activity_main.xml` file:

**replace**

```
android:onClick="my40th"
```

**with**

```
android:onClick="loadImagefromGallery"
```

Comment: activity_main.xml code - <Button
        android:id="@+id/my40th"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/xmas"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:onClick="my40th"
        android:text="My 40th"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="50sp"/>

Comment: Do you check by changing `android:onClick="my40th"` to `android:onClick="loadImagefromGallery"`? Still your code show `android:onClick="my40th"`

Answer (score 0):

What i will suggest you to do is to follow that approach for this scenario:

1. Declare the AppCompatButton from your layout in java and don't forget to remove the onClick attribute form widget in xml

```
    private AppCompatButton mButton;
```

2. onCreate map it with the corresponding ID from xml and setOnClickListener to this

```
    mButton = findViewById(R.id.button_send); 
    mButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

3. Override the onClick method and handle the operation of click inside it

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) 
    { 
        switch (view.getId()) { 
        case R.id.button_send: 
            // your method or calculations goes here 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Removing the onClick attribute from the mainactivity.xml will stop the user from being able to click that attribute and take them to the specific page. I want the user to click on the onClick attribute, take them to that specific page and then from there click another button to select an specific image from their phone gallery.

Comment: I am referring to this activity "my40th ". Let me understand it clear, your scenario is : You have a button in mainactivity.xml and onClick of it you go with intent to my40 activity where you need to get an image from gallery when you click on this specific button. So what i am suggesting to you is that this button ("AppCompatButton ") which is located in your xml layout of my40 activity, remove from it the attribute onClick in xml, and define it as above. Inside switch/case just call the loadImagefromGallery method at the view matches your button id.

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of your project structure ? (The activitys and layouts you  have)

Comment: I'm completely lost now, only a beginner at this. What should the myth.java look like?

Comment: That's why i asked for a screenshot of project structure, because you are being a little bit confuse. It's not that hard at all, the reason why your app crashes is because it's missing the reference of widget. can you post your whole xml in order to help you to solve this problem ? use [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) to send me your xml code.

Comment: Ok lets test something else, follow the instructions in this [link](https://pastebin.com/9jwnLrnk)